# Porquê que serialize form retorna valor de textarea vazio?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Boa noite,

Estou a criar um `CMS` baseado em `bootstrap` `php` e `ajax` o que me acontece e que consigo enviar os dados do `form` todos por método `POST` menos o valor da textarea retorna sempre vazio estou a usar o `tinymce` como editor de html.

**Código usado**

```
<script> 
$(document).on("click", "#novo", function(e) { 
    var postData = $("#form_novo").serialize();
    var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
    var url = $("#url").val();
    if(titulo === '' || url === ''){
        toastr.error('Preencha os campos obrigatórios!', 'Campos');
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modulos/footer/guardar.php",
            data: postData,
            cache: true
        }).done(function(msg) {
            toastr.success('Dados guardados com sucesso!', 'Footer');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!', 'Erro');
        });
    }
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que com o [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/), a `textarea` deixa de existir e a edição do texto passa a ocorrer numa `iframe`.

O `.serialize()` vai localizar elementos, mas a `textarea` não está em uso, logo vai um valor vazio.

## Soluçao 1

Adicionar um campo escondido no teu formulário:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="texto" name="texto" />
```

E depois, antes de chamares o `.serialize()`, podes ir buscar os dados da `iframe` do *tinymce* e passa-los para o campo escondido da seguinte forma:

```js
$('#texto').val(tinyMCE.get('meuTinymce').getContent());
```

## Solução 2

Também podes dizer ao *tinymce* para passar as alterações para o elemento `textarea` antes de chamares o `.serialize()` da seguinte forma:

```js
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

## Solução 3

Também podes anexar um evento ao formulário para que antes do `.serialize()` ele diga ao *tinymce* que deverá passar os valores atualizados para a `textarea`:

```js
$('#idMeuFormulario').bind('form-pre-serialize', function(e) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

## Solução 4

Ao iniciares o *tinymce* podes instruir o mesmo para estar sempre a sincronizar a `textarea`:

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

---

<sup>Estas e outros soluções nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2122085/352449) do SOEN.</sup>

Comment: Acabei por optar por a solução 2 parece mais simples e funcionou certinho. obrigado pela ajuda